# Manga where young girl found a boy who turns into a fox

Tags: story-identification, manga

So, I hope I can give enough details about this. I want to surprise my gf by finding this for her. She was young and in Hong Kong when she read these so probably 15 years ago or so (the comics themselves could be older) and I imagine it would have been in Cantonese (the comics could have just been translated from Japanese or Mandarin).

Basically a girl finds a fox or a boy who can turn into a fox, and there is also another boy who can turn into a (black) fox who is like a bad version or something? They may or may not have been ghosts.

That's really all the information I have. I don't want to straight up ask her the name of it (don't know if she even remembers the name) because she would know I'm looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Kajika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kajika)?

> Kajika is the story of title protagonist and his quest to return to being a normal boy. As a member of the Kawa Tribe (カワ族, Kawazoku), Kajika is extremely strong and has special powers. As a child, Kajika was very evil. His greatest known evil was chasing after a defenseless fox and smashing it with a giant rock. Upon being killed, the spirit of the fox cursed Kajika and Kajika was turned into a fox-man.

[image]

Comment: This might potentially be it, the time frame is right. However, the plot wikipedia has, doesn't quite sound like what she told me. I also can't find references to this being translated to Cantonese (though maybe most Japanese mangas were). I will try to secretely dig for more details so I can provide more plot points. Kajika was also never translated to english so I can't read bits of it to see if the story relates. Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: @Villan - There's a lot of illicit translations out there. It wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if it was a grey (or even black) import being sold openly.

Comment: @Villan: Did you ever find out if this matched?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, I could not find it. But I don't think it is. She talked as if the series revolved around the girl and not the fox.

Comment: @Villan - I think now might be the time to probe for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Kanokon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanokon)* (or rather, the manga adaptation of it).  It's actually the other way around (girl is fox, boy is clueless), but it's close enough to be a possible match, especially given the presence of a black wolf-spirit.

> Kanokon's story revolves around Kouta Oyamada, an extremely innocent young first-year high school student who moves from the country to the city and thus transfers to Kunpō High School. On his first day at his new school, he meets a beautiful second-year female student named Chizuru Minamoto. Chizuru asks him to meet her alone in the music room. When he arrives, she tells him that she is in love with him and accidentally reveals to him that she is in fact a fox spirit. Chizuru constantly and openly flirts with Kouta, even in front of others, embarrassing him greatly. Soon after the story begins, a wolf spirit named Nozomu Ezomori transfers into Kouta's school and class. From day one, she is all over Kouta, serving to embarrass him more and causing Chizuru to become annoyed at her new competition for Kouta's affection.

[image]

Comment: No, I know for sure specifically the boy was the fox and the girl was normal. I also don't think the timeline adds up as the manga was made in 2006 and she came to Canada around that time. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamisama_Kiss probably also too late. Girl finds fox spirit. Rival is a black raven